# TableView Positioning and Resizing

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

what i am trying to make is a view which also has a tableview inside, the table view is to be positioned half the way down the page. At the top of the page there are going to be Images and labels etc, the main issue is getting the tableview at the bottom of the page and also being able to insert data into the table using a plist. I have tried many different methods in resizing and the position of tableViews but of yet nothing has worked. If you have any advice or a tutorial please let me know, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put your images and labels at top of page into the header view of your tableview. See tableview.tableHeaderView property.

Answer (score 0):

set the position programmatically

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, Width, Height)];
```

You can set the position also height and width.